# Weird gap between divs

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with weird gaps between divs.
Divs are collapsable and it appears it is causing an extra couple of pixels between them. It's not margin, just a gap.

Here is a sample of my code. The left side "GameName" menu item is clickable.

I am creating the collapse effect by just adding and removing display style on click:

```
if (panel.style.display === "block") {
    panel.style.display = "none";
} else {
    panel.style.display = "block";
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMzyMp

Comment: It's not really clear what "weird gap" means, can you take a screenshot and point out exactly what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weird gap comes from a bottom margin on a child (`<ul>`), added by default browser styles on `<ul>`s.

```
.locations ul {margin-bottom: 0}
```

[fixes it](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/PRzExx).

Answer (score 1):

Your gap is actually a margin of `<ul>` element, added by the browser. Try this:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```